# Sesión en Laravel 4 expira rápido

Tags: php, laravel

Amigos, estoy trabajando en un sistema en Laravel 4.2 en el cual no utilizo el ORM.

Pues verán, luego que el usuario inicia sesión creo:

```
Session::put('keyUsuario',objUsuario)
```

Luego, creo un filtro para validar en el cual coloco un:

```
if(Session::has('keyUsuario'))
```

De esa manera válido el acceso a los controladores con un:

```
$this->beforeFilter("nombre_filtro")
```

Pues verán, luego de cada cierto tiempo se pierde la sesión y me envía a la vista de logueo como está programado, a veces no pasa ni un minuto que inicio sesión y se pierde.

Estoy usando el Driver `file` y el `Lifetime` esta en 120.

¿Alguna sugerencia de lo que podría estar pasando?

**P.D.:** Como servidor local utilizo Wamp Server.

Comment: podrías agregar que valor tienes en tu php.ini para gcmaxlifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 4.2 almacena las sesiones en archivos no utiliza lo de php nativo.

Para solucionar este problema he creado mi propia clase que Administre las Sesiones nativas de PHP.

Answer (score 0):

si tienes configurado :

```
driver  = file
lifetime = 120   (120 minutos para mantener la sesión)
```

probablemente tendrás que comentar dentro de tu `php.ini` el valor de `session.gc_maxlifetime` para que tome los valores dentro de tu `session.php`